# How to get Bitmap of android screen?

Tags: android, performance

I want to capture the android screen in Bitmap without taking the screenshot.
please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Check out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-in-android

Comment: I want to get Bitmap without taking the screenshot of the screen. please help me in how to do it.

Comment: `I want to get Bitmap without taking the screenshot of the screen.` Are you aware that **this is a nonsense**?

Answer (score 5):

Try this :

```
private void takeScreenshot() {
    Date now = new Date();
    android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

    try {
        // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
        String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg";

        // create bitmap screen capture
        View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        File imageFile = new File(mPath);

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        int quality = 100;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

        openScreenshot(imageFile);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        // Several error may come out with file handling or OOM
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You can view the file like this :

```
private void openScreenshot(File imageFile) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Add this permission to save your file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: I want to get bitmap not of the particular app but of any screen that is displayed to the user.
Secondly i want to know do we need to develop a app to get bitmap of any android screen or can we do it through jar file also.

Comment: @Gazal `I want to get bitmap not of the particular app but of any screen that is displayed to the user` In simple words: **you aren't allowed to**.

Comment: Can we take bitmap only for image not for android screen ?
If so , then can we take pixel value directly from the screen without creating bitmap?